# How to read such construction?

Tags: c#, .net

I've jumped into such a thing in my code and I don't really know how to read this. Would be nice if somebody could help me with this :)

```
return Company?.Call?.SingleOrDefault(cf => cf.Name == Client?.CallID) 
    ?? Company?.Call?.SingleOrDefault(cf => cf.IsDefault) 
    ?? new CallData();
```

Comment: Some people just like to watch the world burn...

Comment: might return a invalid result in case `Client` is null and `Company.Call` with name `null` exists

Comment: That's what you get when you apply every ReSharper suggestion. It's fun to write, but unreadable. Sometimes code needs to be explicit. There are like five business rules here that should be accompanied by a comment, pointing to or explaining the specifications. A couple of `if()` statements don't hurt anyone.

Comment: Wait, SingleOrDefault might return default, why does the second statement (after the first ??) try to return the default, if theres neither a Single or a Default? Isn't it checking for default a second time (useless code)?

Comment: The name of the `SingleOrDefault` method has nothing to do with the name of the `IsDefault` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?.` operator is called a **Null-conditional** operator and is a new feature from C# 6, and was announced in October 2014. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx

The first part: `Company?.Call?.SingleOrDefault` can be seen as similar to this:

```
if (Company == null)
{
    return null;
}
else if (Company.Call == null)
{
    return null;
}
else
{
    return Company.Call.SingleOrDefault(....
}
```

But then the original coder uses the `??` Null-coalesce operator, which has been a part of C# since at least 2007. It means that if whatever is left of the `??` is `null`, evaluate what is right of the `??` and return that instead.

So the code basically means:

- If `Company` is `null`, return `new CallData()`
- If `Company.Call` is `null`, return `new CallData()`
- If the first call to `Company.Call.SingleOrDefault` returns a `CallData` instance *(having a certain value for the `Name` property)* , return that instance
- If the first call returns `null`, but the second call returns a `CallData` instance *(being the default one)* , return that instance
- If both calls to `SingleOrDefault` return `null`, return `new CallData()`

This piece of code has some issues.

First of all, it is unreadable and should be refactored into something that is easier to understand. New language features are nice, but only when used responsibly.

Second: If there are more than one `CallData` instances with the same `Name`, the `SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception, but there might be a unique index in the database the prevents this. The same goes for `IsDefault` property - if there are more than one records with `IsDefault = true`, the `SingleOrDefault` call will throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Split it to 3 expressions first, separated by the `??`:

```
Company?.Call?.SingleOrDefault(cf => cf.Name == Client?.CallID)
??
Company?.Call?.SingleOrDefault(cf=>cf.IsDefault)
??
new CallData();
```

The returned value of the *entire* expression would be the first expression that is returning a non-null value.

Within each segment, once any of the properties accessed using `?.` is `null`, the entire expression will be evaluated to `null`.

See [Null-conditional Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx)